# overload unique_ptr operator call make_unique

Tags: c++

I would like to add a operator to std::unique_ptr so i can add make_unique without adding make_unique to code

i would like to be able to do it something like this

```
namespace Window
{
    class CWindow;

    typedef std::unique_ptr<CWindow> Window;

    template<typename... Args>
    Window::operator=(Args&&... args)
    {
        return std::make_unique<CWindow>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
}

//global
Window::Window MainWindow;

//In WinMain
MainWindow = Window::CWindow("Window Name", Vector2D(10, 10), Vector2D(500, 500));
```

Comment: Why not `template <typename...Ts> Window CreateWindow(Ts&&...args) {return make_unique<CWindows>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);}` ?

Comment: Because im adding other windows controls this way that have pointers to the main window / tabs

Comment: `operator=` accepts only one argument. Why don't you simply assign `unique_ptr` made using `make_unique` to `MainWindow`?

Comment: @GeorgeSovetov How you mean?

Comment: `MainWindow = std::make_unique<Window::CWindow>("Window Name", Vector2D(10, 10), Vector2D(500, 500))`.

Comment: @GeorgeSovetov thats how i was doing it, i just thought there might of been a nicer looking way of adding stuff.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. `operator=` must be a member function, and you cannot add your own stuff to the `unique_ptr` class.

Even if it were possible, it would be a bad idea because:

- it would break the behaviour of valid use cases of `operator=` for `unique_ptr`
- people reading the code will not expect this unexpected behaviour

You *could* derive from `unique_ptr` and overload `operator=` in the derived class, but again it will confuse anyone reading the code (including yourself probably, if you revisited the project after a period of time).

As suggested in comments, it would be better just to make some named function.

Comment: `unique_ptr` is a template and you can add your own partial specialization though the standard threatens you with UB in this case.